# Mapbox gl js, 3d marker

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925979/mapbox-gl-js-draw-a-car-marker) question, is it possible to inject 3d model and use it as a marker in Mapbox GL? And, if yes, how to do it?

Comment: See https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3996

Comment: thanks, that is usefull

Comment: Probably too late as of now but you can also link 3d models with three.js linked to Mapbox via threebox.js.