# Mapbox GL JS - "Flat" Marker

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

For a project I am currently working on, I want to use mapbox-gl-js to implement in-car navigation on a raspberry pi (using offline map data and OSRM for routing). I want to display the current position on the route using an arrow marker - just like in Google Maps (I know, this could easily be done using Mapbox markers, but...).

Is it in any way possible to add a "flat" marker that is always on the same plane as the map, even when the view is tilted/pitched (i.e. the marker image becomes squished and oval when tilted, and round when viewed from above)? This behavior in GMaps can be seen here: [Maps marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb0El.jpg) - the white circle is oval and the arrow shorter compared to when viewed from above.

Searching on SO and the internet did not provide any meaningful answers (except possibly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925979/mapbox-gl-js-draw-a-car-marker), but the link to the example is dead). I know this could very likely be implemented using a custom GL layer, but that seems rather complicated for the problem at hand...

I also noticed that a GEOJson source of type "image" is displayed with such an effect, so as a last resort I could probably calculate the required four edge coordinates from the current position. Though I'd gladly use a simpler method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Symbol Layer with the layout property [`"icon-pitch-alignment": "map"`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#layout-symbol-icon-pitch-alignment).

An example https://jsbin.com/hoziqeb/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for! Guess I just didn't look thorough enough ;-)